# Adding to list performance due to encrypted data

Tags: c#, sql, list

I have created a system whereby a lot of sensitive data has to be encrypted in the database. The issue I face is querying the data with filters, like First Name, Last Name etc. As these values are encrypted inside the database, my only solution at the moment is to bring back ALL data and add to a List, and query the list. This is causing some performance issues.

I have tired Dictionary, HashSet and Parallel methods to increase the speed but to no luck.

The below function is a IQueryable method that brings back 800 records from the database. This SQL query runs in about 0.02 seconds.

```
var data = dc.GetSensativeData();
```

I then create an instance of a List.

```
var listItems = new List<T>();
```

I then loop through the query (800 records) and to the list. I am decrypting some of the values within the foreach loop.

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
    listItems.Add(item);
}
```

800 records are taking around 15 seconds to render the page which is far too long.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to query your encrypted data in the database, have a look at `homomorphic encryption` (though I doubt that that will really solve your problem). Another common approach is to let the server keep the data unencrypted in memory and only encrypt it when writing to disk. With encryption you have to pay the price of decryption somewhere. Right now that's in your client.

Comment: It depends too on which encryption method you use. I would recommend to use a StopWatch (in System.Diagnostics) for each statement in the foreach loop to see exactly what is slowing down the process.

Comment: assuming you are using the same key to encrypt everything, and everything is encrypted independently, and encryption for each value produces unique values... and and and.... then you may be able to encrypt your query term and compare the encrypted results with the stored values.  However, the correct answer is what @germi stated - let the database engine handle the encryption.

Comment: The c# Encryption and Decryption method is what is slowing it down. 2 items within the list need to be decrypted. If I remove those, the query takes 0.06 seconds from 15 seconds. Can anyone recommend articles to quick c# Encryption and Decryption methods?